# should I use “experience” or “experiences”?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is proper?

> One of the most beautiful **experience**

or

> One of the most beautiful **experiences**

Comment: *One of* basically means *one out of* which suggests plurality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an apple when there are many apples, it's "one of the apples". When you say "one of X", even if X is a phrase, you generally want X to be plural.

Thus, it is "one of the most beautiful **experiences**".